# Is the outgoing connection from a OpenVPN client to a LAN behind an OpenVPN server forwarded by the server kernel?

Tags: iptables, openvpn, kernel, forwarding, tun

I've observed a somewhat strange behavior that I can't quite understand. So I set up an OpenVPN connection as shown in the graphic below. (It's a TUN and client-to-client setup).
My thoughts are directed towards the route of ping in this scenario:
[my openvpn connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnlzI.png)

```
 from client: 192.168.200.102 to LAN: 10.198.0.16
```

In general, it's nothing surprising that this ping is successful, but for my comprehensions, in case when I change my iptables settings on the server to

```
-P FORWARD DROP
```

and then even

```
 net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0.
```

the traffic should never reach the destination with the above settings. Although the traffic is successful, it kinda never does reach the LAN interface. The thing is I can't see the traffic (by running tcpdump data-network packet analyzer) arriving at the LAN interface eth0 10.198.0.16. More it seems that the tun interface is self answering the traffic, like if the LAN IP was bind to the tun interface, see below:

```
sudo tcpdump -i tun0 tcpdump: 16:34:21.391381 IP 192.168.200.102 > 10.198.0.16: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1885, length 64 16:34:21.391514 IP 10.198.0.16 > 192.168.200.102: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 1885, length 64
```

What's is happening here? As far as I understand, the request coming from the Client goes to tun interface on the server and will be eventually **FORWARDED** by the kernel to eth0, am I right? Would that normally be visible by running:`sudo tcpdump -i tun0` or `sudo tcpdump -i eth0`?

Why I'm so picky about this thing is that I consider it a security risk if there isn't a way to implement rules to prevent Clients from accessing the LAN on the server. What am I missing here, is there an OpenVPN process that itself forwards packets to the eth0 interface (as intended for client-to-client configuration)?

To let you better help me out of my problem I attached some diagnostic below.

**For the Server**

1. `ip addr`

   ```
   `1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
       link/ether b8:27:eb:5c:a6:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 10.198.0.16/24 brd 10.198.0.255 scope global eth0
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe5c:a6e6/64 scope link 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
       link/ether b8:27:eb:09:f3:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
       link/none 
       inet 192.168.200.1/24 scope global tun0
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::87cd:fedd:92fc:cde/64 scope link stable-privacy 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```

`

2. `ip route`

   ```
   default via 10.198.0.1 dev eth0 proto static 
   10.198.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.198.0.16 
   192.168.200.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.1 
   192.168.178.0/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev tun0 scope link
   ```
3. `server openvpn.conf`

   ```
   tls-server
   mode server
   dev tun
   local 10.198.0.16
   proto tcp-server
   port 1234
   user openvpn
   group openvpn
   ca /etc/openvpn/cacert.pem
   cert /etc/openvpn/servercert.pem
   key /etc/openvpn/serverkey
   dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
   ifconfig-pool 192.168.200.2 192.168.200.103 255.255.255.0
   client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
   ifconfig 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.0
   keepalive 10 120
   comp-lzo
   client-to-client
   push "topology subnet"
   topology "subnet"
   log /var/log/openvpn.log
   ```

**For the Client**

1. `ip addr`

   ```
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 38:af:d7:a0:52:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 00:28:f8:8d:1c:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet 192.168.178.79/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
          valid_lft 859868sec preferred_lft 859868sec
       inet6 2a0a:a540:d54:0:bd79:eb10:5e26:548a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
          valid_lft 7190sec preferred_lft 3590sec
       inet6 2a0a:a540:d54:0:6086:b044:dff:2694/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
          valid_lft 7190sec preferred_lft 3590sec
       inet6 fe80::ad5c:6e18:87fa:dff4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
       link/none 
       inet 192.168.200.102/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global tun0
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::5dfc:6b3a:3c4d:e9a4/64 scope link stable-privacy 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```
2. `ip route`

   ```
    default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
    10.198.0.0/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev tun0 
    192.168.200.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.102

    192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.79 metric 600
   ```
3. `client openvpn.conf`

   ```
    dev tun
    client
    nobind
    remote 11.22.33.44
    proto tcp
    port 1234
    ca /etc/openvpn/cacert.pem
    cert /etc/openvpn/user_cert.pem
    key /etc/openvpn/user
    comp-lzo
    verb 3
    keepalive 10 120
    log /var/log/openvpn.log
   ```
4. `ccd for client`

   ```
   iroute 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traffic between the VPN and the rest of the network of course is going through `tun0`. For this traffic, `FORWARD` chain is consulted as usual and you can control who can connect where. If `ip_forward` is not enabled, the traffic will not be forwarded.

When `client-to-client` is not used, the traffic between clients uses the same path: it appears in the server OS from `tun0` interface, routes properly using OS routing table, traverses the firewall, and the only difference is that it decides the destination is behind `tun0`, so packet is egressed through it.

It is not very efficient, because OpenVPN process is in the user space, while tun0 is in the kernel space, and it results in at least two context changes for each packet.

When `client-to-client` is used, however, packets between clients don't appear on `tun0`, and server's firewall `FORWARD` chain is not consulted and the `ip_forward` control does not influence their forwarding. The OpenVPN process itself becomes a router, with its own routing table, independent from the hosting OS. You can see it with the `status` command of management interface or dump it into the status file. You can control routes within this "router" with `iproute` directive (I believe it stands for "internal route"), which is only valid in the client's `client-config-dir` file or script-generated dynamic configuration.

Easiest is to not to think of VPN as something special. Once the tunnel is established, forget about it, it is now just an additional regular interface in each computer (server and clients), with all those interfaces connected to some regular simple router.  And consider usual routing and firewalling.

---

I finally noticed that you ping the address of *the VPN server itself* albeit assigned to other interface. This packet is *not going to be forwarded* anyway because its destination is server itself so the `ip_forward` doesn't influence how this packet is processed, and it is traversing `INPUT` firewall chain and the reply will traverse `OUTPUT` (e.g. not `FORWARD` chain as they would if they weren't destined to the system itself). The packet will enter the system from `tun0` (and will be seen there), but you won't see it on the `eth0` because it is not going to be sent away. It will be processed locally. The same is true for replies.

It doesn't matter (to the routing-related code) where on the system the address is assigned (which interface), or which address of the system you use to access it. What matters is whether it belongs to the system or not.

---

The related security issue is that some people think that if they bind the service to some IP address assigned to some interface they cut the access to this service through other interfaces. **This is wrong.** If other systems living behind other interfaces have route to the IP where the service is bound, they still *will be able* to access the service. This is not a correct way to secure the service; proper firewall setup is.

Another related issue is that some people use `ping -I <local-address> <address-to-ping>` or even `ping -I <interface> <address-to-ping>` and they think they directly select which interface pings will go out. Again, this is wrong. This way you can only select which *source address* pings will have, but not the interface to send them; the interface will be selected by the routing code strictly according to the routing table based solely on destination address of the packet (I presume no VRF or RPDB setup was done, but that is advanced stuff and people who set it up know about this feature anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've heard about it and understand that for efficiency, the connection between VPN clients should go through the VPN process, rather than the system kernel. But in my example, the connection ends up going on the server from tun0 to eth0 (10.198.0.16)! So how one wants to connect eth0 (10.198.0.16) from tun0 on the server without going through the system kernel?

Comment: As explained in the first paragraph, the only way is through the system kernel. You should see the traffic both on `tun0` and `eth0`. If you don't see the traffic or can't block it, probably, you're doing something wrong in that part.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!

Comment: But you know what, I've now checked and on the tun0 interface I can of course see the traffic coming from the client. But I don't see any traffic on the interface to which the LAN IP is located. There must be more behind it, why should the traffic be successful but not visible on the interface!?? And if I disable the client-to-client configuration and suddenly see the pings on the LAN IP interface.. what then, how should I understand that? If you get what I mean, wouldn't that mean that there might not be kernel forwarding? Is something like that possible at all?

Comment: Here a snapshot: `sudo tcpdump dst 10.198.0.16 -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
16:29:09.951767 IP 192.168.200.102 > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1574, length 64`

Comment: Here another snapshot without "dst" option: `16:34:21.391381 IP 192.168.200.102 > ubuntu: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1885, length 64
16:34:21.391514 IP ubuntu > 192.168.200.102: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 1885, length 64`

Comment: Can you see now? It is like tun0 is self answering the ping!? - where ubuntu of course is 10.198.0.16

Comment: It looks like you set up some NAT. Don't hide private network addresses: it doesn't identify you, it doesn't help security, but it does make much harder to understand what you are talking about and to help. If you want such detailed answer please include [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1117753/edit): `ip addr` and `ip route` run on *all three systems involved* (you can mask out public IPs), `iptables-save` on the middle system, and OpenVPN server and client config with keys, certificates and `remote` masked.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, of course I simply pasted in the result of tcpdump, and as written above "ubuntu" stands for the LAN IP. And all in one my problem is just one thing: why can I ping the LAN address of the OpenVPN server without the system noticing that kernel forwarding is taking place? Is there any mechanism in OpenVPN that allows it to be waived?

Comment: Ah, you pinged from the VPN address of VPN server's other interface? Let me reiterate, had you provided from the beginning all the information I asked for and don't hide it under cryptic "ubuntu" word, I'd answered this right away. Because *it is not being forwarded*. It is not going through `FORWARD` chain, rather, it is routed to localhost and therefore it uses `INPUT` chain (and replies traverse `OUTPUT` consequently). It doesn't make any difference which address of the system you access and which interfaces they are assigned to, all of them are equal, important is which system you access.

Comment: Hey, I rewrote my question, edited as you asked, and please let me know, a feedback would be very nice! Also see the new graphic!